# Formula for filtering multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Currently using Excel 2016 version form my desktop at work.

I came into a complicated issue of creating a formula to filter multiple criterias.

Filter certain values from 1 coloum, applying a formula to calculate the duration of difference of time, filtering for location, and finally filtering for company.

Here is my data sheet.

[image]

[image]

1. need to filter from column F, only those contain, 3,5,6,7,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,21,22,23
2. calculate the time duration between column O and L
3. Results from Point 2, need to be sum together categorized  by column X and Z(in the 2nd picture for reference)

Hope to hear news from anyone on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share the formula you have tried so far,, help us fix the issue!

Comment: There is a fairly basic two-stage formula if you repair the datetimes in column O. Ensure that there are both date and time components to the values and that the values are true dates, not text-that-look-like dates.

Comment: 1. create a helper column to perform step 2. 2. create a lookup table with the values that qualify for step 1. 3. `SUMIFS` with the 'duration' helper column as the sum_range, criteria_range1 is `F:F`, criteria1 is the valid values in the helper table, criteria_range2 is `X:X` or `Z:Z` (depending which of the tables in the second image you're in) and criteria2 is the location name you're summarizing. That should be enough to get you started - you can come back and ask for more help if you run into trouble setting up those initial components.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. need to filter from column F, only those contain,
>      3,5,6,7,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,21,22,23

Select all data > Data > Filter > select values for column f

> 2. calculate the time duration between column O and L

(while the filter is active) at the rightmost, use extra column (say.. column AA) and put the formula : `=o7-l7` (if the 1st filtered value is from row 7. Copy the formula and paste downwards.

> 3. Results from Point 2, need to be sum together categorized by column X and Z(in the 2nd picture for reference)

Assuming the "Bukit Panjang" text is located in B1, Sheet2. put in B3:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$X$2:$X$35,B1,Sheet1!$AA$2:$AA$35)
```

and drag rightwards. edit accordingly for column z.

Please share if it works/not. ( :